# How does iOS knows which location manager delegate to call on region monitoring while the app is not running?

Tags: ios

I might be confusing how region monitoring works, but this is what i have so far:

I am registering a region to monitor through my location manager, which is implemented on a singleton class, this singleton is also set as the delegate of the location manager so the implemented method is being called.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

This works totally as expected, if the app is active or suspended the method is being called. It also makes total sense because the class has been already loaded and when the region enter event occurs iOS sends this even to my app which calls the location manager who registered (probably has a reference to it) and in turn it calls whatever delegate was also registered along it (since the class is there ready and loaded).

The issue is, what happens when the app has been killed? Is it first launched into the background? How does iOS know what delegate method to call, and if it has already been loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your app has been killed and gets started for a location update there can't be a location manager delegate yet and as such there are no notifications delivered to that delegate. The system can't know which of your classes should be used as a location manager delegate or how to instantiate it.

Instead your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` gets called as usual, but the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` is set in the options dictionary. That tells your app that you need to instantiate a location manager and set it's delegate. Only after you did this the delegate gets called with the region updates.

Comment: So there are two different flows right? 1 with my app alive and the other without it. By the way, after receiving the dictionary with that key on the app launch should I handle that specific notification? or is the location manager being monitored for when I set it up to be instantly delivered? (Im talking about the notification that made my app launch)

Comment: That's correct. In most cases you would pass the location value given as a launch option to whatever is handling location changes in your app, and potentially start monitoring for location changes in your app as well. You were started with a new location - do something with that location value and start monitoring for location changes.